# Как получить SID группы и размер буфера, в который он записывается?

Tags: winapi

Необходимо получить Sid группы, а не пользователя... По примеру функции

```
     BOOL WINAPI LookupAccountName(
     LPCTSTR lpSystemName,
     LPCTSTR lpAccountName,
     PSID Sid,
     LPDWORD cbSid,
     LPTSTR ReferencedDomainName,
     LPDWORD cchReferencedDomainName,
     PSID_NAME_USE peUse
     );
```

Данная функция позволяет получить SID пользователя, но не группы... 
Может быть кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой же проблемой и знает решение... Прошу помочь..